How to separate the scroll state in tab layout in Android Compose Ui
I'm drawing a UI with Android Compose.
It consists of two tabs, each showing data in a LazyColumn.
Since the data type is the same for both tabs, we've drawn the UI with a single LazyColumn.
The code looks like this
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val items1: SnapshotStateList<Item> = mutableStateListOf()
    val items2: SnapshotStateList<Item> = mutableStateListOf()

    var selectedTabIdx: Int by mutableStateOf(0)
        private set

    fun onTabSelected(idx: Int) {
        selectedTab = idx
    }
}


@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    selectedTabIdx: Int,
    itemList1: List<Item>,
    itemList2: List<Item>,
    onTabSelected: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    TabUi(...)

    ItemList(
        items = if (selectedTabIdx == 0) itemList1 else itemList2
    )
}

@Composable
fun ItemList(
    items: List<Item>
) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(items) { item ->
            ItemUi(item)
        }
    }
}

The problem is that after scrolling on the first tab, when the second tab is selected, the second tab is scrolled to the same position.
If you duplicate the code as shown below, the problem is solved.
@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    selectedTabIdx: Int,
    itemList1: List<Item>,
    itemList2: List<Item>,
    onTabSelected: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    TabUi(...)

    if (selectedTabIdx == 0) {
        ItemList1(
            items = itemList1
        )
    } else {
        ItemList2(
            items = itemList2
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ItemList1(
    items: List<Item
) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(items) { item ->
            ItemUi(item)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ItemList2(
    items: List<Item>
) {
    LazyColumn {
        items(items) { item ->
            ItemUi(item)
        }
    }
}

However, this code also has a problem: if you scroll in the first tab, press the second tab, and then press the first tab again, the previous scroll is not preserved.
There's also the issue that the code itself is duplicated.
How can I fix this?

Check out the signature of the LazyColumn Composable:
@Composable
fun LazyColumn(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    state: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState(),
    // ...
    content: LazyListScope.() -> Unit
): Unit

The LazyColumn offers a state attribute that takes an object of type LazyListState. In this LazyListState, the scroll position is stored. If you don't provide a LazyListState, the LazyColumn will create its own local one.
When you wrap a Composable in an if statement and the Composable is hidden, it is removed from the composition completely, and all its local state will be lost. So when you show the LazyColumn again after hiding it, the LazyListState will be newly generated.
The first approach would be to store the LazyListState of both LazyColumns outside of the if statement as follows:
@Composable
fun MyScreen(
    selectedTabIdx: Int,
    itemList1: List<Item>,
    itemList2: List<Item>,
    onTabSelected: (Int) -> Unit
) {
    TabUi(...)

    val scrollState1 = rememberLazyListState()
    val scrollState2 = rememberLazyListState() 

    if (selectedTabIdx == 0) {
        ItemList(
            scrollState = scrollState1,
            items = itemList1
        )
    } else {
        ItemList(
            scrollState = scrollState2,
            items = itemList2
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun ItemList(
    scrollState: LazyListState,
    items: List<Item
) {
    LazyColumn(
        state = scrollState
    ) {
        items(items) { item ->
            ItemUi(item)
        }
    }
}

Note that you can use the same ItemList Composable twice, there is no need to have ItemList1 and ItemList2.
The second approach would be to use a HorizontalPager. It is very commonly used together with a TabRow and has some benefits:

You can swipe between pages
When you navigate between pages using the Tabs, you get a nice animation
The individual pages will not be reset while navigating between pages

Have a look at this Github Sample to see how to synchronize a TabRow with a HorizontalPager. In your case, you could simply place the if into the HorizontalPager like this:
HorizontalPager(
    //...
) {
    if (selectedTabIdx == 0) {
        ItemList(
            items = itemList1
        )
    } else {
        ItemList(
            items = itemList2
        )
    }
}

